# panel event not working (sencha touch)

Tags: javascript, sencha-touch-2

I want to add an intro page to my sencha touch (ext js for mobile devices) that redirect user after some time for this i want to use panel event listener that if found in various documents, i implemented it like this :

```
    Ext.define('myapp.view.intro', {
    extend: 'Ext.Panel',
    config: 
    {
       fullscreen: true
    },
    listeners:
        { 
            resize: function(intro, w, h) {
            alert('Panel resized to ' + w + 'x' + h);
        }
        }


   });
```

but when i open it with chrome(web-kit) nothing happens(i tested many other events like 'render' and ..) no errors occurred too!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

listeners should go inside the config object